# Error while while opening an activity

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.applexus.PROJMANAGER/com.applexus.PROJMANAGER.CalendarType}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class 
com.applexus.Scheduler.CalendarView
```

I get this error when clicking my Calendar activity.

This is a calender view which am using in my activity and I 
get the error while opening the activity. Here is the code:

```
public class CalendarView extends ImageView {
private static int WEEK_TOP_MARGIN = 74;
private static int WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = 40;
private static int CELL_WIDTH = 58;
private static int CELL_HEIGH = 53;
private static int CELL_MARGIN_TOP = 92;
private static int CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = 39;
private static float CELL_TEXT_SIZE;



private static final String TAG = "CalendarView"; 
private Calendar mRightNow = null;
private Drawable mWeekTitle = null;
private Cell mToday = null;
private Cell[][] mCells = new Cell[6][7];
private OnCellTouchListener mOnCellTouchListener = null;
MonthDisplayHelper mHelper;
Drawable mDecoration = null;

public interface OnCellTouchListener {
    public void onTouch(Cell cell);
}

public CalendarView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mDecoration = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.typeb_calendar_today);      
    initCalendarView();
}

private void initCalendarView() {
    mRightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    // prepare static vars
    Resources res = getResources();
    WEEK_TOP_MARGIN  = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.week_top_margin);
    WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.week_left_margin);

    CELL_WIDTH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_width);
    CELL_HEIGH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_heigh);
    CELL_MARGIN_TOP = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_margin_top);
    CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_margin_left);

    CELL_TEXT_SIZE = res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_size);
    // set background
    setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
    mWeekTitle = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_week);

    mHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(mRightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR), mRightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH));

}

private void initCells() {
    class _calendar {
        public int day;
        public boolean thisMonth;
        public _calendar(int d, boolean b) {
            day = d;
            thisMonth = b;
        }
        public _calendar(int d) {
            this(d, false);
        }
    };
    _calendar tmp[][] = new _calendar[6][7];

    for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
        int n[] = mHelper.getDigitsForRow(i);
        for(int d=0; d<n.length; d++) {
            if(mHelper.isWithinCurrentMonth(i,d))
                tmp[i][d] = new _calendar(n[d], true);
            else
                tmp[i][d] = new _calendar(n[d]);

        }
    }

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int thisDay = 0;
    mToday = null;
    if(mHelper.getYear()==today.get(Calendar.YEAR) && mHelper.getMonth()==today.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        thisDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    // build cells
    Rect Bound = new Rect(CELL_MARGIN_LEFT, CELL_MARGIN_TOP, CELL_WIDTH+CELL_MARGIN_LEFT, CELL_HEIGH+CELL_MARGIN_TOP);
    for(int week=0; week<mCells.length; week++) {
        for(int day=0; day<mCells[week].length; day++) {
            if(tmp[week][day].thisMonth) {
                if(day==0 || day==6 )
                    mCells[week][day] = new RedCell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
                else 
                    mCells[week][day] = new Cell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
            } else {
                mCells[week][day] = new GrayCell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
            }

            Bound.offset(CELL_WIDTH, 0); // move to next column 

            // get today
            if(tmp[week][day].day==thisDay && tmp[week][day].thisMonth) {
                mToday = mCells[week][day];
                mDecoration.setBounds(mToday.getBound());
            }
        }
        Bound.offset(0, CELL_HEIGH); // move to next row and first column
        Bound.left = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT;
        Bound.right = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT+CELL_WIDTH;
    }       
}

@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    Rect re = getDrawable().getBounds();
    WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = (right-left - re.width()) / 2;
    mWeekTitle.setBounds(WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN, WEEK_TOP_MARGIN, WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN+mWeekTitle.getMinimumWidth(), WEEK_TOP_MARGIN+mWeekTitle.getMinimumHeight());
    initCells();
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}

public void setTimeInMillis(long milliseconds) {
    mRightNow.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    initCells();
    this.invalidate();
}

public int getYear() {
    return mHelper.getYear();
}

public int getMonth() {
    return mHelper.getMonth();
}

public void nextMonth() {
    mHelper.nextMonth();
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public void previousMonth() {
    mHelper.previousMonth();
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public boolean firstDay(int day) {
    return day==1;
}

public boolean lastDay(int day) {
    return mHelper.getNumberOfDaysInMonth()==day;
}

public void goToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public Calendar getDate() {
    return mRightNow;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(mOnCellTouchListener!=null){
        for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
            for(Cell day : week) {
                if(day.hitTest((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    mOnCellTouchListener.onTouch(day);
                }                       
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setOnCellTouchListener(OnCellTouchListener p) {
    mOnCellTouchListener = p;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw background
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mWeekTitle.draw(canvas);

    // draw cells
    for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
        for(Cell day : week) {
            day.draw(canvas);           
        }
    }

    // draw today
    if(mDecoration!=null && mToday!=null) {
        mDecoration.draw(canvas);
    }
}

public class GrayCell extends Cell {
    public GrayCell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float s) {
        super(dayOfMon, rect, s);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }           
}

private class RedCell extends Cell {
    public RedCell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float s) {
        super(dayOfMon, rect, s);
        mPaint.setColor(0xdddd0000);
    }           

}
}
```

Comment: maybe you get problem with your layout xml file, can you give more detail your layout xml file

Comment: can you paste some of your code

Comment: the problem is in your xml which is being inflated at line number 60.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the xml file? Is there are problems with that? Your log says inflate exception, so I think it probably caused by your xml layout or something wrong with the inflating process. you can post your activity's source code here, and we will see what we can do to help

Comment: can anyone help me with a solution for this??